# Regular pattern error for Amazon Rekognition index-faces method calling from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I am following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-perform-facial-analysis-on-live-feeds-by-creating-a-serverless-video-analytics-environment-with-amazon-rekognition-video-and-amazon-kinesis-video-streams/

However, when I run the command

```
        aws rekognition index-faces --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":" 
       <S3BUCKET>","Name":"<MYFACE_KEY>.jpeg"}}' --collection-id 
    "rekVideoBlog" -- 
       detection-attributes "ALL" --external-image-id "<YOURNAME>" --region 
    us- 
       west-2
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: 3 validation errors detected: Value '"Alex"' at 'externalImageId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.\-:]+; Value '"rekVideoBlog"' at 'collectionId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.\-]+; Value '["ALL"]' at 'detectionAttributes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy enum value set: [ALL, DEFAULT]]
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I replaced the single quote with double quotes and double quotes with escaped double quotes (\") so it'd work but I got that error.

Comment: Have same error - at 'collectionId' failed to satisfy constraint : Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.\-:]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051643/invalids3objectexception-when-calling-the-indexfaces-operation. If you feel that this is not a duplicate of your earlier question, feel free to edit this question and incorporate the steps recommended in the answer on the previous question. Otherwise, if the provided answer assisted in resolving this issue you can accept the answer to assist others who might run into the same issue.