# InvalidS3ObjectException when calling the IndexFaces operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am attempting the following tutorial

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-perform-facial-analysis-on-live-feeds-by-creating-a-serverless-video-analytics-environment-with-amazon-rekognition-video-and-amazon-kinesis-video-streams/

So I replaced some part with my own bucket and key(file) name:

```
aws rekognition index-faces --image "{\"S3Object\":{\"Bucket\":\"testbucket\",\"Name\":\"testfile.png\"}}" --collection-id=rekVideoBlog --detection-attributes=ALL --external-image-id=Andy --region us-west-2
```

(assume testbucket is my bucket name and testfile is the file I uploaded and made public). Is this correct?

I have made sure to set the bucket and object public etc but I keep getting an error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
```

I also tried to access my bucket using:

`aws s3 ls s3://testbucket`

and I am able to display the content fine

Answer (score 2):

are you currently facing this error : ***"An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the IndexFaces operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions"***?

I was able to run the sample Amazon Rekognition CLI command **"index-faces"** from the [Amazon Rekogniton tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-perform-facial-analysis-on-live-feeds-by-creating-a-serverless-video-analytics-environment-with-amazon-rekognition-video-and-amazon-kinesis-video-streams/) without any error as illustrated in the screenshot below :

[image]

Here's some tips for consideration in-case anyone else runs into this issue :

- Make sure both S3 & Rekognition are using the same region **i.e** ***S3 bucket should be created in the same region as where Rekognition collection was created.***
- Since Amazon Rekognition supports both **.jpg** and **.png** formats, make sure the file name & format referenced in the CLI **“index-faces”** command matches the actual file in your S3 bucket.

Hope this helps.